# Creating instance of class within class

Tags: java, oop, class

Consider that I have the two following nested classes:

```
public class Foo {

    public class Bar {

    }

}
```

And my goal is to create an instance of class `Bar`. I've tried to do it the following ways:

```
// Method one
Foo fooInstance = new Foo();
Foo.Bar barInstance = new fooInstance.Bar // fooInstance cannot be resolved to a type

// Method two
Foo.Bar barInstance = new Foo.Bar(); // No enclosing instance of type Foo is accessible
```

Any help would be highly appreciated, I'm stuck. As you might notice, I'm a Java-beginner: which doesn't automatically make this a homework question (as a matter of fact - it isn't).

**How can one create an instance of the `Bar` class? Preferably with the same `Foo` instance.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Close. Instead write:

```
Foo.Bar barInstance = fooInstance.new Bar();
```

Answer (score 3):

Here:

```
Foo.Bar barInstance = new fooInstance.Bar // fooInstance cannot be resolved to a type
```

you try to instantiate a type that doesn't exist (fooInstance is just a variable)

The right way to do that is, as explained:

```
Foo.Bar barInstance = new Foo().new Bar()
```

Here:

```
Foo.Bar barInstance = new Foo.Bar(); // No enclosing instance of type Foo is accessible
```

this is valid only for static inner classes of Foo. So, make Boo a static inner class of Foo if this fits your needs

Answer (score 2):

You have to create object of inner class like :

```
Foo.Bar barObj = new Foo().new Bar();
```

If inner class is static, then you can create them directly as :

```
public class Foo {    
    static public class Bar {    
    }    
}
```

```
Foo.Bar b = new Foo.Bar();
```

Comment: +1 for making the inner class static if you can. Instantiating a non-static inner class from outside the containing class may indicate a problem with your design.

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
Foo.Bar barInstance = new Foo().new Bar();
```